# Solution to Modular Congruence: $3^{47}\mod23$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am trying to solve the following modular congruence but I am not sure how to proceed as I have not fully grasp the concept of it.

$$\large3^{47} \mod 23$$

I would like to know how to proceed in solving this while understanding the process in doing so.

Comment: Do you have Euler's theorem?

Comment: Somewhat, but I don't fully understand it. Would you mind explaining?

Comment: A special case of the theorem says that, when $p$ is prime, $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ for any nonzero $a \in \mathbb{Z}$.  In this problem, a good first step would be recognizing that $3^{47} = 3^{22 + 22 + 3} = 3^{22}3^{22}3^3$ and applying that fact.

Comment: Do you think you can post an answer demonstrating the full process?

Comment: @OmariCelestine It would be a better idea to try the hint first, and then ask again if you don't understand. This will help you better understand the process, not the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Use *lil' Fermat*: as $23$ is prime and $3$ is not divisible by $23$,
$$3^{47}\equiv3^{47\bmod 22}\mod23.$$

Some details:

$47\bmod 22=3$, so $\;3^{47}\equiv 3^3=27\equiv 4\mod23$.

Comment: And that would be the solution?

Comment: You have to end the computation, naturally.

Comment: could you please demonstrate? As I mentioned, I have not grasped the concept of modular congruence as yet.

Comment: I've added the computation. All you have to know is that $a\equiv b\mod 23$ means $a$ and $b$ have the same remainder in the division by $23$, and $a\bmod23$ denotes this remainder. Is that clearer?

Comment: @Randall: Right. I was thinking of $\varphi(23)$. Fixed. Thanks for pointing it!

Comment: What does φ(23) mean? Also, where did the $3^{3}$ come from?

Comment: It is *Euler's totient function* which gives the number of units modulo $n$. For a prime number $p$, its value is $p-1$. The exponent of $3$ is the remainder  when you divide $47$ by $22$.

Answer (score 3):

Another way of stating Fermat's Little Theorem is $a^p\equiv a$ mod $p$ for *any* $a$ if $p$ is prime.  Thus we have

$$3^{47}=3^{23+23+1}=3^{23}\cdot3^{23}\cdot3\equiv3\cdot3\cdot3=27\equiv4\mod23$$